# If $F(x) = 0$ for all points on the interval $[a,b]$ except $c$ then $F$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Suppose $c$ is a point in the closed $[a,b]$ and that $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ except for $c$ and that $F(c) = 1$. Show that $F$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and that $\int_a^bF(x)dx = 0$.

By another question I asked, I was told that a function need not include an endpoint for it to be integrable (so if I said $f(x)$ is integrable on $[1,2]$, it's also integrable on $[1,2)$.) Could I say that $\int_a^bF(x)dx = \int_a^cF(x)dx + \int_c^bF(x)dx$ and that both of the latter integrals $=0$ or is that not a strong enough proof? The problem I'm coming across for any other explanation is the discontinuity at $c$ because instead of a discontinuity along an interval, it's a single point of discontinuity.

I cannot use Riemann integrability to solve the problem, so if the explanation could exclude responses with Riemann integrability, that would be much appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: Is the following a possible solution:

The Cauchy Criterion for Integrability says F is integrable if given $\epsilon,\exists P_\epsilon$ such that $U(F,P) < L(F,P) + \epsilon$. So let P be a partition such that the distance of every interval is $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ ie $\Delta x_i = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

$L(F,P) = \sum m_i\Delta x_i = \sum 0* \frac{\epsilon}{2} = 0$

$U(F,P) = \sum M_i\Delta x_i = \sum 1* \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon = 0 + \epsilon = L(F,P) + \epsilon$

Since the Cauchy Criterion for Integrability holds, F is integrable.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use Riemann integrability? What's your definition of integrable?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that a lot of other posts say something along the lines of "Riemann Integrable" instead of simply integrable. We've used Darboux integrability in our proofs thus far.

Comment: Oh ok. Then I think you need to just do it. Given epsilon, just take a partition that has a very small interval < epsilon in width about the point c. Now lower sum is zero, upper sum is less than epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $c \in (a,b)$, and consider the partition
$P_\epsilon = (a,c-{1 \over 2} \epsilon, c+{1 \over 2} \epsilon, b)$. Then
$L(f,P_\epsilon) = 0$, $U(f,P_\epsilon) = \epsilon$.

Comment: This would prove that $F$ is not integrable, wouldn't it?

Comment: This would prove integrability...

Comment: But $U(F,P) \neq L(F,P)$? I'm confused how this proves integrability.

Comment: Use the Cauchy criterion that you mentioned above to show integrability, and the value of the integral follows from the fact that $L(f,P) =0$ for all partitions $P$. (In general, one has $L(f,P) \neq U(f,P)$, so I'm not sure what you mean there...)

Comment: For F to be integrable, U(F) must equal L(F), and that's when inf(U(F,P)) = sup(L(F,P)). I don't understand how saying U(F,P) not equal to 0 proves the integrability.

Comment: Clearly $\sup L(f,P) = 0$ and $\inf U(f,P) = 0$. However, for **any** partition $P$, you have $U(f,P) > L(f,P) = 0$.